# flex4 Scrolling with mouse move

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

How can I scroll  a group in flex4 with the movement of the mouse position?

Would like it to scroll on the mouse X position.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [setValue()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/HScrollBar.html#setValue%28%29) method on the scroll bar component to automatically scroll.

You should be able to access the specific scroll bar from your sccroller:

```
scroller.horizontalScrollBar.setValue(mouseXPosition);
scroller.verticalScrollBar.setValue(mouseYPosition);
```

Add that code in an event listener for the [mouseMove](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3amouseMove) event.